# AngularJS: can't get html5 mode urls with ui-route $state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, .htaccess, url-routing

I'm using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) for state management but I think I'm having trouble with my .htaccess rewrite rules. All my states worked when using /#/account style urls. Now I've enabled html5 mode but my app isn't rendering as it was before. It seems to load my index.html and all my js and css files, etc. but not actually initialise any states.

Here is my folder structure:

```
root/
    app/
        components/
            angular/
            ...
        images/
        scripts/ 
            controllers/
            directives/
            ...
            app.js       
        styles/
        views/
        .htaccess
        ...
```

My vhosts DocumentRoot points to my `app/`

Here is my app.js with my states:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('appointeddPortalApp',  ['ngResource', 'ui.state', 'ui.compat', 'fundoo.services', 'ui.date', 'ngCookies'])
.config(function ($stateProvider, $routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {

    var access = routingConfig.accessLevels;

    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"];
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $stateProvider
    .state('root', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '',
        views: {
            'header': {
                templateUrl: 'views/partials/header.html'
            },
            'search': {
                templateUrl: 'views/partials/search.html',
                controller: 'SearchCtrl'
            },
            'main': {
                templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
                controller: 'MainCtrl'
            },
            'footer': {
                templateUrl: 'views/partials/footer.html'
            },
        },
    })
    .state('root.home', {
        url: '',
        views: {
            'content': {
                templateUrl: 'views/home/index.html',
                controller: 'MainCtrl',
            }
        },
        access: access.anon
    })
    .state('root.about', {
        url: '/about',
        parent: 'root',
        views: {
            'content': {
                templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
                controller: 'StaticCtrl'
            },
            'search@': {}
        },
        access: access.anon
    })
    .state('root.search', {
        url: '/search/:city/:category',
        views: {
            'content': {
                templateUrl: 'views/search.html',
                controller: 'SearchCtrl'
            }
        },
        access: access.anon
    })
    .state('root.salons_profile', {
        url: '/salons/{id}',
        views: {
            'content': {
                templateUrl: 'views/salons.profile.html',
                controller: 'SalonCtrl',
            },
            'search@': {}
        },
        access: access.anon
    })
    .state('root.account', {
        url: '/account',
        abstract: true,
        views: {
            'content': {
                templateUrl: 'views/user/account.html',
                controller: 'AccountCtrl'
            }
        },
    })
    .state('root.account.info', {
        url: '',
        views: {
            'account_head': {
                templateUrl: 'views/user/account.head.html',
            },
            'account_body': {
                templateUrl: 'views/user/account.my_appointedd.html',
            },
        },
        menus: {
            'account': {
                identifier: 'my_appointedd',
                class: 'active'
            }
        },
        access: access.user
    })
    .state('root.account.appointments', {
        url: '/appointments',
        views: {
            'account_head': {
                templateUrl: 'views/user/account.head.html',
            },
            'account_body': {
                templateUrl: 'views/user/account.appointments.html',
            },
        },
        menus: {
            'account': {
                identifier: 'appointments',
                class: 'active'
            }
        },
        access: access.user
    })
    .state('root.account.details', {
        abstract: true,
        views: {
            'account_head': {
                templateUrl: 'views/user/account.head.html',
            },
            'account_body': {
                templateUrl: 'views/user/account.details.html',
            },
        },
        access: access.user
    })
    .state('root.account.details.account', {
        url: '/details',
        views: {
            'right': {
                templateUrl: 'views/user/account.details.account.html',
            },
        },
        menus: {
            'account': {
                identifier: 'details',
                class: 'active'
            },
            'settings': {
                identifier: 'account',
                class: 'active'
            }
        },
        access: access.user
    })
    .state('root.account.details.profile', {
        url: '/profile',
        views: {
            'right': {
                templateUrl: 'views/user/account.details.profile.html',
            },
        },
        menus: {
            'account': {
                identifier: 'details',
                class: 'active'
            },
            'settings': {
                identifier: 'profile',
                class: 'active'
            }
        },
        access: access.user
    });


})
.run( [ '$location', '$state', '$stateParams', '$rootScope', '$cookies', 'Auth', function( $location, $state, $stateParams, $rootScope, $cookies, Auth){

    $rootScope.client_id = '51a741eb3152c3ae7e000103';
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
    $rootScope.$cookies = $cookies;

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
        if (!Auth.authorize(toState.access)) {
            if(Auth.isLoggedIn()) $state.transitionTo('root.account');
            else                  $state.transitionTo('root.home');
        }
    });
```

Here is my rewrite code that sits in .htaccess in /app. I think this is might be wrong.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks 
  RewriteEngine On 
  RewriteBase / 
  RewriteRule ^(components|images|scripts|styles|views)($|/) - [L]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This configuration has worked for many of our Apache users using html5mode and ui-router.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my-app

    DocumentRoot /path/to/app

    <Directory /path/to/app>
        RewriteEngine on

        # Don't rewrite files or directories
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^ - [L]

        # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
        RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Also please make sure you are not a victim of `<base href>` bug. See the [ui-router FAQ](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#issue-my-assets-and-templates-are-not-loading) for more info.

Comment: Hi nfiniteloop, it seems my issue was the <base href> bug! Thanks!

Comment: you rock. +1. noobs... you can drop everything from inside the `<Directory` node into .htaccess on root and you'll have the same effect on your web host. cheers!

Comment: in drupal how will is set when i set this rule 500 Internal Server Error comes please help

Comment: But is then not every route lost and I get always redirected to home? E.g. `mypage.de/abc` will be redirected to `mypage.de/index.html` instead of `mypage.de/#/abc`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with child states "admin.classes". I get a 404 not found. I did add this rule to my htaccess file: RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ /$1 [R,L]. When i do a page reload on /admin/classes. I get routed to /classes.

Comment: Never mind I did not have the <base href="/"></base> in my <head></head> Cheers! I now can refresh /admin/classes and get to the same spot.

Comment: If you are using apache >2.2 you may use `FallbackResource` instead - as an example `<Directory /api> FallbackResource index.html </Directory>` more to be read here: [fallbackresource apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource)

Answer (score 3):

If working in a shared hosting that doesn't allow to edit Apache configuration you can set this in your `.htaccess` file to make `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` work (as @Shanimal pointed in @nfiniteloop answer):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /path/to/app #change this!

# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

And don't forget to add `<base href="/path/to/app/">` in the HTML `<head>`.