# HTML5 Mode AngularJS ui.router

Tags: angularjs, html, .htaccess, angular-ui-router

Hi I want to use html5 mode. My file structure is as the following:

```
mypage.de/mysub
```

I can only mess around in mysub.

So far, I added into my index.html:

```
<base href="/mysub/">
```

And created a new (and the only one) .htaccess in /mysub/

```
RewriteEngine on

# Don't rewrite files or directories

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

If I use an url:
`mypage.de/mysub/#/site1` it is transformed into `mypage.de/mysub/site1` and loaded

But if I use the transformed url directly, e.g.: `mypage.de/mysub/site1` I get a 404

The server is an apache:
I looked into that tutorial:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

But I'm not sure what server-name is & if /path/to/app is

```
/
```

or

```
/mysub/
```

Also it throws my already an internal server error when I just leave the virtual host & the part within the directory tags.

because the .htaccess is within the directory. I tried diff. varaitions but nothing worked here so I just used the part within Directory as mentioned here:
[AngularJS: can't get html5 mode urls with ui-route $state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444072/angularjs-cant-get-html5-mode-urls-with-ui-route-state)

Comment: Also doesn't it cut the whole #/sitex part? Wouldn't be s.th. like this better:
mysub\/(#\/)?(.*)$ in the regex

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /mysub/

  # Don't rewrite files or directories
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]

  # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
  RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Doesn't work it just shows the 404, so I think he doesn't rewrite.

Comment: I tried this in a test.php:
<?php echo in_array('mod_rewrite', apache_get_modules()); ?>
It gives back 1: so it seems to be enabled

Comment: Is RewriteBase relative to my document root? E.g. 
/srv/www/html/mysite.de/mysub/
Do I need mysub or /srv/www/html/mysite.de/mysub/

Comment: And he does read the .htaccess, because putting garbish in it causes an internal server error.